# jenkins_configure_proxy role missing in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have Ansible 2.4.0. I am trying to configure Jenkins proxy based on [Ansible Jenkins DevOps Roles documentation](http://ansible-jenkins-roles.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
- hosts: master
  roles:
    - jenkins_configure_proxy:
      jenkins_home: "{{ jenkins_home }}"
      proxy_host: "{{ proxy_host }}"
      proxy_port: "{{ proxy_port }}"
      become: true
      environment: "{{proxy_env}}"
```

When trying to execute ansible_playbook I get:

ERROR! role definitions must contain a role name

```
The error appears to have been in '/Users/me/projects/jenkins/jenkins.yml': line 10, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - jenkins_configure_proxy:
      ^ here
```

That pretty strange, because other roles like `jenkins_plugin` work fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You use role syntax without parameters to apply role with parameters, see example:

```
- roles:
    # without or with default parameters
    - jenkins_configure_proxy
    # with custom parameters
    - role: jenkins_configure_proxy
      jenkins_home: "{{ jenkins_home }}"
      proxy_host: "{{ proxy_host }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still raises same error "ERROR! the role 'jenkins_configure_proxy' was not found in ..."

Comment: And do you have `jenkins_configure_proxy` under `./roles/` directory?